# Open TextView when clicking FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I put a text box for typing the user by clicking the floating button?

The user would type the word to be found or could delete the text by clicking X at the end of the Text

[image]

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing this post with any new information you had, any new code you'd tried, or an explanation of why the posted answer isn't working would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed this question as a duplicate of the newer one, since that one is better fleshed out, but, in the future, please just edit the original.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **FrameLayout** with an **EditText** then set its visibility to **Gone**.
Finally set **onClickListener()** to **FAB** to make its Visibility **visible**.

Comment: I did it here, but it was not aligned, it stayed on top of the activity. How could I leave the left side of the FloatingActionButton

Comment: Okay use RelativeLayout instead of FrameLayout and then write EditText in the very bottom of the RelativeLayout it will make EditText to come foremost of the views.
Then use **android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/FAB_ID"** to align the EditText to the left of FAB

Comment: I could not, I lost hours trying I need to do exactly according to the image: https://imgur.com/a/CHJ3B